# PHP namespacing and folders

Tags: php, namespaces

If I have a **System** folder in the root directory containing a **Database** folder with a ***Database.php*** file which holds a class

```
class Database{
   static function Connect(){
      echo "connect";
   }
}
```

And I call that from an `index.php` which is in the root directory.

How do I make a namespace to access the class `Database::Connect();`
I really am struggling with namespaces.

Do I need to put `namespace System\Database` at the top of my Database.php file or something? Any good examples that aren't on php.net pages?

Comment: 5.3.10 or 5.3.13, doesn't matter which I can switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces (in PHP) are really just a way of preventing naming collisions between Classes in a project. They have been used for a some time (before they were officially supported) in the form of classes named things like "Zend_Controller_Action_Helper".
The PHP5.3 introduction of "real" namespaces really just means we can now use short, readable names in our code by "use"ing a namespace.

eg.

file: system/database.php

```
namespace MyProject;

class Database {
// ...
}
```

file public/index.php

```
require_once '../system/database.php';

// here we have to use the fully qualified name of the Database class,
// this is similar to the old unofficial underscore method.
$db = \MyProject\Database::connect();
```

file: public/index2.php

```
require_once '../system/database.php';
use MyProject\Database;

// here we can simply use "Database" because the "use" statement says:
// for this file we are using the "Database" class from the "MyProject" namespace
$db = Database::connect();
```

Namespaces are only related to directories by convention (and for autoloading) they, in an of themselves, don't change the way classes are included and used.

Comment: Cheers, good answer too... namespacing is fine, do it in c#.net and c++ and java.. just wanted to check the syntax coz I didn't see php.net reference folders.

Comment: If I do "echo Database::Ass();" and I have a method called Ass in my Database, it runs the Ass method and outputs what I need... If I have a static variable "public static $Ass = "hi"; and echo that, it doesn't work.. any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to echo the static variable? it should be `echo Database::$Ass;`, not `echo Database::Ass;` To differentiate between a variable and a method.

Comment: Ahh thank you.. why was I doing it that way. hah! I think i'm having "episode la noob"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to namespace your Database class to System\Database, you'll need to add this above your class declaration:

`namespace System\Database;`

Then, when calling the Connect method:

`\System\Database\Database::Connect();`

Your file structure is only relevant to your namespaces when it comes to auto-loading the files you want to include in your scripts, so if you are going to manually include Database.php in your scripts you can make the namespace whatever you want.